# Get the Most Number of Questions from Tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I am new to this website and I am still learning how to post and get answers, so, please be patient on me.

I would like to know how do we get 3 tags at most the will give the most number of questions related to a topic. For example, suppose that the combinations of the following tags [tag1][tag2] (e.g. [sacla][akka]) give more than 500 questions related to a certain topic (e.g. actor programming in Akka). Can we generalize this to other tags such that once we write 3 tags it will give the most number of topics/posts related to these 3 tags?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? Search bar? Asking a question? Elaborate please.

Comment: You can create a query for this on SEDE.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ. My question is not when asking question but when searching for questions with certain topic. The point is how to make sure that such a tag combination will give the most number of questions related to a topic? Some posts have the same topic but could be tagged differently and that is the problem.

Comment: @Ibraheem, part of the confusion over your question is that tags are generally used the other way.  Some sites have hundreds of thousands of posts.  Tags are used to narrow the list to a manageable number to look at by trying to focus the search as narrowly as possible.  You get more posts captured in the net by using worse (i.e., less-specific, less-focused), tags, or fewer tags.  re: questions tagged differently--sometimes you may need to do multiple searches to get them all, or use "or", as ColeValleyGirl describes.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for your answer. I understand that, but it seems the other way around is difficult to achieve, i.e., to narrow/get/have tags based on a certain topic in mind as the one mentioned in my question above.

Comment: @dfhwze SEDE allows you to run queries on questions bassed on XML attributes in the row of each question in SO data dump. I am not sure if SEDE will give the most number of tags related to a topic?

Answer (score 1):

The search help https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching explains that if you combine two tags as you suggest "[scala](/questions/tagged/scala)[actor](/questions/tagged/actor)", you will find the questions that have both of the tags you request.

If however you use "[scala](/questions/tagged/scala) or [actor](/questions/tagged/actor)" you will find questions with either of the two tags.

There is no way using the site search facility to be certain you get all possible related questions unless you search for all the possible tags and/or words in contents.  However, users who are expert in a particular topic will always try to ensure that tags are used consistently.

Comment: Thank you Cole. I understand how tags combination works, but the thing I am asking about is how do you know that such a combination will give you the most number of questions related to a certain topic? The same topic could be tagged differently or tags are not the same despite having the same topic.

Comment: @Ibraheem I have updated my answer. dfhwze has suggested toy use SEDE but I'm not familiar with the tool, so can't answer with regard to that.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Since the question is ON HOLD, I'll put my SEDE query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/1134844/get-the-most-number-of-questions-from-tags. Although, I don't really know what the user exactly wants.

Comment: @dfhwze, I tried other combinations on your query like [azure-service-fabric][c#] and it did not give me anything back. What I am trying to ask is for any certain topic in Stack Overflow/Exchange, how we can get a set of tags related to that topic that will give us the most number of questions related to that topic? For example, for topic such as actor programming in Scala, [scala] [actor] [akka] will give the most number of questions related to that topic (500 questions), but any more tags added will reduce that number, for instance [scala] [actor] [akka] [sharding].

Comment: @Ibraheem that would make it more complex, especially since we need some way to determine what exactly a 'topic' is and how we can distinguish topics from other topics.

Comment: @dfhwze, I tried tags co-occurrence matrix,  and I picked the 3 most frequent tags related to [azure-service-fabric], but that is not tangible progress since we could easily do that by simply searching on the search bar/SEDE in Stack Overflow/Exchange, which will give the same result. Some questions are about the same topic but they were tagged differently so they will have opted from the result which makes the analysis wrong as this will not give the most number of questions based on tags combinations for a certain topic. Do you think clustering, classification, topic modelling might help?

Comment: @Ibraheem without a clear classification it would just be guessing in the dark I'm afraid.